# For those who have changed from parse to backendless....Do you have issued with ARC in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

We have changed from Parse to Backendless and it seems that deallocation of DateFromatter is not being done efficiently. Does anyone have thoughts on this? or has experienced similar problems.

Best,

Feras A.

Comment: What exactly happens "deallocation of DateFromatter is not being done efficiently"

Comment: no deallocation. Basically the memory in the app continually increases. Although small increases this adds up and is causing memory issues.